# How to order cells of a table using Pander

Tags: r, r-markdown, pander

I am using the pander function to make my tables in R markdown, but having some troubles with cells being ordered in an illogical way.
[here is a screenshot of my r Markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeWvR.jpg)
As you can see, it is ordering based on the first digit as opposed to the value of the whole number. 
here is my script:

```
income.frequency.table <- xtabs(~income, data=iceland)
pander(income.frequency.table)
```

any help would be really appreciated. I am very new to R and coding in general so apologies if I've missed something very obvious!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please `dput()` your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are characters that just happen to be numbers, so the sort is lexical, not numeric. This is why e.g. `1900000` precedes `400000`; because `1` precedes `4`.

A general solution to this is to make the text an ordered factor. The intended order will be preserved.

```
x <- c("4", "10")
sort(x)  # unexpected
# [1] "10"  "4"

y <- ordered(x, levels = c("4", "10"))
sort(y)  # as intended
# [1] 4  10
# Levels: 4 < 10
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I reordered the text using the reorder function in the g.data package, and now it's working fine.